# Can python SWIG bind a library in the absence of the library's source code?

Tags: python, c, swig

The software tool [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) can be used to create a programming interface (bindings) to C/C++ software for other languages.

Interfacing to a C library works fine when the original C source code is available, from which one compiles .so files. The sample commands are listed in the SWIG python documentation: http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_nn7

However, in my case the 3rd party C library does not come with source files, only the header files. It comes with .dylib files under Mac OS X, and not .so files.

Is it possible to create a python module with a binding to this C library?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6193120/168175 - The same question but with Java as the target instead of Python. The "link your SWIG library against the one you're wrapping" is by far the nicer solution for python. I can elaborate more if that's not clear.

Comment: Looks like @Flexo elaborated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10126794/116047)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SWIG, header files are enough to generate the interface files. Though I haven't worked on MacOS, so not sure on how to link those libraries. But regarding your first question, you dont need the source code of a library to swig it to c/c++.